# Proper way of adding TeXlive to PATH

Tags: macos

I am trying to use VScode LaTeX workshop on mac ventura and I am receiving

Recipe terminated with fatal error: spawn latexmk EN0ENT

when compiling.
I am trying to follow the LaTeX workshop instructions but I am not sure how to add set path environment variable. I tried to add the texfile location to PATH with different methods including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh), but I still receive the error and PATH always get reverted back after restarting terminal.

I am very new to command line and using zsh atm.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! Maybe restring your PC can help. That's what solved my problems for several times.

Comment: Exactly what did you install on your Mac? I know of at least 3 ways to install LaTeX on a Mac. The one most used, aka MacTeX should automatically add it self to the relevant path.

Comment: I installed VScode and BasicTeX with homebrew. I tried installing MacTex with .pkg and with homebrew but neither worked.

Comment: I would probably not install from homebrew and it gets _complicated_ exactly what happened with installing MacTeX? And is your Mac OS version among the supported ones?

Comment: The exact same problem occurs when I installed MacTeX. I want to install with homebrew because I want to get more into command line programming. Regardless it didn't work with either methods.

Comment: @Jonathan The homebrew cask basically just uses the MacTeX installer anyway, so there's no reason to use homebrew to install MacTeX. I would uninstall the homebrew installation and start over with a regular MacTeX. Then the path should be set correctly. With your current installation what does `which pdftex` return in the terminal?

Comment: <which pdftex> returns pdftex not found but if I navigate to /usr/local/texlive/2022basic/bin/universal-darwin i can see that its there.

Comment: @Jonathan Make sure that `/etc/paths.d` contains a file `TeX` with the single line `/Library/TeX/texbin`.  If it doesn't then create that file within `/etc/paths.d` (you'll need to use `sudo` to do this). Then restart your terminal (and VSCode) and it should work.)

Comment: @AlanMunn It is and it is still not working.

Comment: @Jonathan, is this still a problem or did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using apple's default zsh. It sounds stupid, but make sure the path is correct in `.zshrc`. It should be something like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin:$PATH
```

Then execute `.zshrc` with

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Check now if `which pdftex` or `which latexmk` returns anything.

Comment: I checked and it still does not fix VSCode's LaTeX workshop extension unfortunately but I will update here if I find a fix.